# WPF Get selected item from DataGrid and open a new Window

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid, and in DataGrid are listed users from Database.
I want that , when i click on a member in DataGrid, open a new Window , and show me the members data(Username, Postal code, ... etc what is in the database).
How to open a new window , when i Click on a row?

Solved:

```
   private void dg_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var windowToOpen = new UsersWindow();

        windowToOpen.Show();
    }
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="NameGrid" MouseLeftButtonDown="dg_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

Comment: Nice to hear that. And what is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: My question is: How to open a new window , when i Click on a DataGrid row?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MVVM or doing codebehind?

In any case you should be able to listen on selectedItemChanged and handle it your way

**EDIT**

Ok. Never tried this by myself..
DataGrid has an SelectedItem property. This gives you the first Row in your selection (If you have Multiselect).

So basically you can do in your Codebehind:

```
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var selectedUser = this.theNameOfYourGrid.SelectedItem;
  var windowToOpen = new Window();
  /*
   * Do what you want with your window
   * 
   * 
   */
  windowToOpen.Show();
}
```

and in your XAML

```
<DataGrid SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged" x:Name="theNameOfYourGrid">

</DataGrid>
```

that should it be

Comment: Ok... So please post your code you got so far as modified question. I'll have a look

Comment: Solved :D        private void dg_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var windowToOpen = new UserWindow();

            windowToOpen.Show();
        }